# need to understand AMD behavior in dojo

Tags: requirejs, dojo, amd

I need to understand one behavior of  AMD in dojo.
 In the below example will statement 1 be always executed first and then statement 2 if ready or domReady! not used?

```
 function test() { 
    var abc;  
    require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry){ 
    //some modification of abc variable.
     console.log("statement 1");----> statement 1 
    });  
    return abc;----> statement 2  
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope... statement 1 will be fired once dijit/registry has been loaded. There is no guarantee that this will be the case when you reach statement 2.

Only the statements inside your require callback are ensured to fire in order.

The above is valid even if you use ready or domReady!

You do try the following to expose your function globally :

```
require(["dojo/_base/kernel", "dijit/registry"], function(kernel, registry){
    kernel.global.test = function(){
        var abc;
        //some modification of abc variable.
        console.log("statement 1");----> statement 1
        return abc;----> statement 2  
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks...Actually i need to exposed the function name globally if I add the function into AMD i am not able to access the function is there any way to do this, also i tried to add the return statement2 in the module itself but it is not returning the any value. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: In my code i have added parseOnLoad:true and asyn: true, however ready  callback is executed before the declarative widgets are loaded. Could you please help me in this regard?

Comment: where is your ready callback ? I can't see it in your code... also it's async:true, not asyn:true. Maybe you should create a separate question, as it looks like a different issue...